# Flutter - Dart variables lost and keep getting reinitialized

Tags: json, variables, static, dart, flutter

I'm trying out things with Flutter right now. But my variables keep getting reinitialised when accessed from another class.

I'm using json parsing and i need two parts of my request. The "Relatorio" part and the "Mensagem" part.

to parse this json i'm doing this:

```
List<RelatorioProdutos> parseRelatorioPorProduto(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  var relatorio = parsed['Relatorio'];
  var mensagem = parsed['Mensagem'];
  print (mensagem); // Here the variable returns well,
 //but when i need it in other class i receive null.

  return  relatorio.map<RelatorioProdutos>((json) => new RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class RelatorioProdutos {
  String CodigoProduto;
  var QtdVendida;
  var TotalVendas;
  String Descricao;

  RelatorioProdutos({this.CodigoProduto, this.QtdVendida, this.TotalVendas, this.Descricao,});

  factory RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(Map json) {

    //returns a List of Maps
    return new RelatorioProdutos(

      CodigoProduto: json['CodigoProduto'] as String,
      QtdVendida: json['QtdVendida'],
      TotalVendas: json['TotalVendas'],
      Descricao: json['Descricao'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use this 'mensagem' variable in another class to show the error for user, but i always receive 'null'.

i already tried setState but it reloads my json and i dont want to request the RestServer again.

Thanks from now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access a local variable of a function from another class. I don't think it's possible.

One way to do it, would be to wrap your response in another object containing the response, and this variable:

```
List<Response<RelatorioProdutos>> parseRelatorioPorProduto(
    String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  var relatorio = parsed['Relatorio'];
  var mensagem = parsed['Mensagem'];
  print(mensagem); // Here the variable returns well,
  //but when i need it in other class i receive null.

  return relatorio
      .map((json) => new Response<RelatorioProdutos>(
          new RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(json), mensagem))
      .toList();
}

class RelatorioProdutos {
  String CodigoProduto;
  var QtdVendida;
  var TotalVendas;
  String Descricao;

  RelatorioProdutos({
    this.CodigoProduto,
    this.QtdVendida,
    this.TotalVendas,
    this.Descricao,
  });

  factory RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(Map json) {
    //returns a List of Maps
    return new RelatorioProdutos(
      CodigoProduto: json['CodigoProduto'] as String,
      QtdVendida: json['QtdVendida'],
      TotalVendas: json['TotalVendas'],
      Descricao: json['Descricao'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class Response<T> {
  const Response(
    this.value,
    this.errorMessage,
  );

  final T value;

  final String errorMessage;

  bool get hasError => errorMessage != null;
}
```

In this example I created a `Response` object that can contains both the response value and an error message.

In the `parseRelatorioPorProduto`, instead of returning the *relatorio*, I changed the return type to `Response<RelatorioProdutos>` in order to have access to the value and the error message from any class which call this function.

Comment: thanks for the help Letsar, but if i do this i get a lot of others errors with List<RelProduto> and List<Responde<RelProduto>>, i did it to fix this problem

Comment: parseRelatorioPorProduto(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  var relatorio = parsed['Relatorio'];
  var mensagem = parsed['Mensagem'];
  if(mensagem[0].toString().substring(16,17) == "0"){
    List<RelatorioProdutos> asd = new List();
    RelatorioProdutos aimeudeus = new RelatorioProdutos(Descricao: mensagem[0].toString(), CodigoProduto: "a", TotalVendas: 0, QtdVendida: 0);
    asd.add(aimeudeus);
    return asd;
  }else{
    return relatorio.map<RelatorioProdutos>((json) => new RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Letsar, i tried yout ideia but i get a lot of others erros.

To solve this problem i used this:

```
List<RelatorioProdutos>  parseRelatorioPorProduto(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  var relatorio = parsed['Relatorio'];
  var mensagem = parsed['Mensagem'];

  if(mensagem[0].toString().substring(16,17) == "0"){
    List<RelatorioProdutos> asd = new List();
    RelatorioProdutos aimeudeus = new RelatorioProdutos(Descricao: mensagem[0].toString(), CodigoProduto: "a", TotalVendas: 0, QtdVendida: 0);
    asd.add(aimeudeus);
    return asd;
  }else{
    return relatorio.map<RelatorioProdutos>((json) => new RelatorioProdutos.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }


}
```